# Git: Pushed changes are being stashed as deleted

Tags: git-push

We use local virtual development servers, which we access through mounted volumes to develop our PHP applications. When working remotely through VPN , this setup is slow.

I cloned the project from my mounted volume into my local drive, which is on the same device. My plan was to push my changes in the office and test at home by uploading the changes on save to the staging server.

This worked fine until I pushed my changes for the first time. Once I push changes from the local repo to the mounted repo all changes were gone. Each line I edited was in it's old stat, as if I hadn't pushed at all.

Looking further into it I found that all changes were on the mounted repo but stashed as deleted. The local repo was not affected by the push. Pulling changes to the local repo works without a problem.

Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Please find an example below

[image]

The pushed commit removed the `.'/'` but on the mounted repo the change was reverted...

Comment: Hi @user3906357, quick one: You said `I cloned the project from my mounted volume into my local drive` Do you mean you cloned the project into your local drive at work or into the local drive in your home pc?

Comment: No. The main repo is on the virtual server which is in the local network at work. I cloned the repo to my local drive... on the same device. Connecting to the mount though VPN makes the IDE painfully slow.

Comment: You lost me in that part `This worked fine until I pushed my changes for the first time. Once I push changes from the local repo to the mounted repo all changes were gone. Each line I edited was in it's old stat, as if I hadn't pushed at all. ` Can you get more precise?